# convert a list column to multiple columns based on a mapping dictionary in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, one-hot-encoding

Lets say I have a pandas dataframe with a column that contains a list:

```
d = {'id': ["First", "Second"], 'list_column': [[1,2,3], [3,2]]}
pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

which looks like this:

```
| id       | list_column |
| -------- | ----------- |
| First    | [1, 2, 3]   |
| Second   | [3, 2]      |
```

and I also have a dictionary that maps the list values to a key, e.g.:

```
dict = {
  1: "red",
  2: "blue",
  3: "green"
}
```

How could I transform my list_column into multiple columns reflecting the contents of the list column, e.g.:

```
| id       | red | blue | green |
| -------- | --- | ---- | ----- |
| First    | 1   | 1    | 1     |
| Second   | 0   | 1    | 1     |
```

Answer (score 6):

You can first explode the column, then map the values using your dictionary, and use [`pandas.crossTab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) to create the desired result:

```py
# df is your dataframe, and dict_ is your dict with key,value pairs
>>> temp=df.explode('list_column')
>>> out = pd.crosstab(temp['id'], temp['list_column'].map(dict_))
```

**OUTPUT**

```py
# out

list_column  blue  green  red
id                           
First           1      1    1
Second          1      1    0
```

Optimized version as suggested by @Mozway in comment:

```py
>>> temp=df.explode('list_column')
>>> out=pd.crosstab(temp['id'], temp['list_column']).rename(columns=dict_)

# out
list_column  red  blue  green
id                           
First          1     1      1
Second         0     1      1
```

It is optimized as it doesn't need to map at row level, rather it just renames the columns after final calculation which is really efficient than the first approach.

Comment: `pd.crosstab(temp['id'], temp['list_column']).rename(columns=dic)` should be more efficient (rename only once, vs multiple times for `map`)

Comment: @mozway thanks for the suggestion, included in answer. That's undoubtedly super efficient compared to the first approach.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
df['list_column'] = df.apply(lambda x: [dic.get(e, e) for e in x.list_column],axis=1)
df.explode('list_column').pivot_table(index=['id'], columns='list_column', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)
```

Output:

[image]